# With Razor is it possible to include a View in a View?

Tags: razor

Te be sure to understand I would like to know if with Razor is it possible to include a View in a View? If yes, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically it's done with some overload of the [`HtmlHelper.RenderPartial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470816) extension method, for example:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName"); }
```

There are also other methods that can be used according to the situation, such as `Partial` (render view to a string):

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")
```

There's also `RenderAction` (render view as specified by controller action).

Comment: I don't want to call a partial view. I want to render a view.

Comment: @DranDane: If you want to render view #2 as part of view #1, then by definition #2 is a partial view. And that's how you render it. Have I misunderstood the question?